# Wget and Nginx can't get contents of localhost

Tags: http, curl, nginx, proxy, wget

I can open my Jenkins at http://localhost:8080 on browser, but wget can't do it.

```
wget http://localhost:8080
--2018-06-12 07:39:56--  http://localhost:8080/
Resolving localhost (localhost)... ::1, 127.0.0.1
Connecting to localhost (localhost)|::1|:8080... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 403 Forbidden
2018-06-12 07:39:56 ERROR 403: Forbidden.
```

And curl can do it:

```
curl http://localhost:8080
<html><head><meta http-equiv='refresh' content='1;url=/login?from=%2F'/><script>window.location.replace('/login?from=%2F');</script></head><body style='background-color:white; color:white;'>


Authentication required
<!--
You are authenticated as: anonymous
Groups that you are in:

Permission you need to have (but didn't): hudson.model.Hudson.Read
 ... which is implied by: hudson.security.Permission.GenericRead
 ... which is implied by: hudson.model.Hudson.Administer
-->

</body></html>
```

The matter is that my **Nginx fails the same like wget**, I get **Error 502 Bad Gateway** on Nginx when trying to route to Jenkins:

This is my Nginx server block for Jenkins:

```
server {
    listen      80;
    server_name ...;

    location / {
        proxy_pass       http://127.0.0.1:8080;
        proxy_redirect   off;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the problem, my Nginx config file is totally correct, Jenkins server working fine, but it is because of SELinux which makes Nginx fail to pass request to Jenkins.

**How to disable SELinux**:

- sudo nano /etc/selinux/config
- Set the line 'SELINUX=' to: "SELINUX=disabled"
- sudo reboot

Answer (score 1):

It seems the page you are hitting is redirecting to other page.
Please check after commenting out proxy redirect and reloading nginx.

```
#proxy_redirect  off
```

Answer (score 0):

Having the exact same configuration and error and investigating this issue for 6+ hours **this** did it to me:

[image]

I needed to check Jenkins > Manage Jenkins > Configure Global Security > Authorization > Allow anonymous read access

Update: I just realized that opens entire Jenkins Software for public reading. Not ideal. I'll need to find a proper solution.